# Why am I getting an undefined control sequence for this mathematical expression?

Tags: errors

I am getting undefined control sequence for this mathematical expression.

```
$D = {{( \textbf(x_n), t_n)}^N_{n=1}} $ where $ x_n \in {\R}^d $ and $ t_n \in {{-1,+1}}$ \\
```

Comment: Unrelated, but ``\\`` is out of place: never end paragraphs that way, use a blank line

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this was copied from a document that has `\R` defined as `\mathbb{R}`. Also, you need to use `\{` and `\}` to get curly braces. I'm guessing you want the `x` to appear in boldface.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

$D = {\{(\mathbf{x}_n, t_n)\}^N_{n=1}} $ where $ \mathbf{x}_n \in {\R}^d $ and $ t_n \in \{{-1,+1}\}$

\end{document}
```